# Question regarding main activity and custom view

Tags: android, xml

I am working on an online handwriting recognition tool . I have a custom view which i am adding to linear layout . how can i get the coordinates in custom view and transfer them to main activity file for storing them in linked lists or array lists

Answer (score 0):

You could override the method OnTouchEvent on your View.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
   float x=event.getX();
   float y=event.getY();
}
```

And then if you want, you could construct a Array or a List.

```
ArrayList<Point> myList;
 ...
//Constructor
 ...
 ...
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x=event.getX();
    float y=event.getY();
    Point p =new Point();
    p.set(x, y);
    //And then add to the list
    myList.add(p);
}
public ArrayList<Point> getMyArray(){
    return myList;
}
```

And for call the method getMyArray of your custom view. You could use this code on your main activity

```
myView mv = (myView)this.findViewById(R.id.myView1);
ArrayList<Point> points = mv.getMyArray();
```

That's a possible solution for your problem but I don't know if it helps you.

Edit: This solution works for all customs View but, if I were you, I would use a View that extends SurfaceView. It's logical because , I think, it's the best way to create graphics in a handwriting tool.

Comment: The onTouchEvent method isn't a member of the view rather the listener that is attached to the view

Comment: It's a member of SurfaceView I have supposed that the custom view extends of SurfaceView because it's a handwriting recognition tool :) I'm going to write it in the post. Thanks

Comment: Actually I just checked the Android docs and onTouchEvent() is a member function of the View class, I was wrong

Comment: I see [(Android Documentation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html). Yesterday, I had no time and you appeared so sure so you made me doubt :). I'm going to edit another time... and thanks for the comments, I've learn a little more about Views

Answer (score 0):

You need create a custom class that implements the OnTouchListener interface and set it to listen to touch events on your custom view.   Its very similar to adding an OnClickListener to a button:

```
MyView view = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myView);
view.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
```

Where MyOnTouchListener looks something like this:

```
class MyOnTouchListener implement OnTouchListener{
public int x=-1,y=-1,prevX=-1, prevY=-1;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    prevX = x;
    prevY = y;      
    int x = (int)event.getX();  
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        // there is no prev touch
        prevX = -1;
        prevY = -1;

        // touch down code

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // touch move code
        // add points to array here!
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // touch up code
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```